# How do you call a method by its "name"?

Tags: c#, reflection, object

What would be the way to call some method by name, like "Method1", if I've got an `Object` and it's `Type`?

*I want to do something like this:*

```
Object o;
Type t;

// At this point I know, that 'o' actually has
// 't' as it's type.

// And I know that 't' definitely has a public method 'Method1'.

// So, I want to do something like:

Reflection.CallMethodByName(o, "Method1");
```

**Is this somehow possible?** I do realize that this would be slow, it's inconvenient, but unfortunately I've got no other ways to implement this in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the concrete method name is only known at runtime, you can't use dynamic and need to use something like this:

```
t.GetMethod("Method1").Invoke(o, null);
```

This assumes, that `Method1` has no parameters. If it does, you need to use one of the overloads of `GetMethod` and pass the parameters as the second parameter to `Invoke`.

Comment: This answer was already posted [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966968/c-reflection-question/5967018#5967018)

Answer (score 11):

You would use:

```
// Use BindingFlags for non-public methods etc
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("Method1");

// null means "no arguments". You can pass an object[] with arguments.
method.Invoke(o, null);
```

See [`MethodBase.Invoke` docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) for more information  - e.g. passing arguments.

Stephen's approach using `dynamic` will probably be faster (and definitely easier to read) if you're using C# 4 and you know the method name at compile time.

(If at all possible, it would be nicer to make the type involved implement a well-known interface instead, of course.)

Comment: @Peter: Fixed - I thought that the second parameter was `params`, but apparently not.

Comment: To confirm Jon's comment about speed, I wrote a simple benchmark.  Using `dynamic` *was* much faster (20-25X), regardless of whether the `dynamic` assignment or the `GetMethod` were placed inside the test loop (these impacted whether the speed difference was 20X or 25X).  Of course, there may be cases where it isn't faster, and it's probably not going to be a bottleneck in most programs.  Nothing fancy, just invoking or calling a function, `sb.Append("A");` on a `static`, `new StringBuilder` (and outputting the length when the test completed) .

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way:

```
dynamic myObject = o;
myObject.Method1();
```

Comment: Not all of us are using C# 4.0.

Comment: And this assumes you know the method at compile-time.

Comment: `And I know that 't' definitely has a public method 'Method1'` - I interpreted this as compile-time knowledge.